# Steam Crashes using PlayOnLinux

Tags: steam, playonlinux

I have an odd problem. Some time ago I used PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu to install Rage (through Steam), this worked and still works perfectly.

I now want to make another Virtual Drive to install SimCity4, this fails when I login to Steam crashing entirely before I even get to the game. The log output is as follows:

http://pastebin.com/3gNzicuS

Since this works right now for another Drive I am confused to say the least. Any help appreciated?

Comment: I cannot install SimCity alongside Rage as Steam has 'no internet connection' but will still allow me to browse the Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Wine 1.7.9 for both the PlayOnLinux Drive and Ubuntu itself.

http://tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint

And inside PlayOnLinux hit Configure and add the newer wine version to that Drive.